# sed - exchange words with delimiter

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying **swap** words around with `sed`, not *replace* because that's what I keep finding on Google search.

I don't know if it's the `regex` that I'm getting wrong. I did a search for `everything before a char` and `everything after a char`, so that's how I got the `regex`.

```
echo xxx,aaa | sed -r 's/[^,]*/[^,]*$/'
```

or

```
echo xxx/aaa | sed -r 's/[^\/]*/[^\/]*$/'
```

I am getting this output:

```
[^,]*$,aaa
```

or this:

```
[^,/]*$/aaa
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` it would be:

```
sed 's#\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/\([[:alpha:]]\+\)#\2,\1#' <<< 'xxx/aaa'
```

which is simpler to read if you use *extended posix regexes* with `-r`:

```
sed -r 's#([[:alpha:]]+)/([[:alpha:]]+)#\2/\1#' <<< 'xxx/aaa'
```

I'm using two sub patterns `([[:alpha:]]+)` which can contain one or more letters and are separated by a `/`. In the replacement part I reassemble them in reverse order `\2/\1`. Please also note that I'm using `#` instead of `/` as the delimiter for the `s` command since `/` is already the field delimiter in the input data. This saves us to escape the `/` in the regex.

Btw, you can also use `awk` for that, which is pretty easy to read:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $2,$1}' OFS='/' <<< 'xxx/aaa'
```

Comment: Not all versions of `sed` will treat `\+` without the `-r` (but they should all handle `\{1,\}` instead), and the equivalent option to `-r` on Mac OS X is `-E`.

Comment: @AdegokeA The substitution will be applied to all lines of the file.

Comment: Basically `sed ... file`. But `sed ... < file` would also work unless you want to change the file in place since sed can read from stdin. Btw, `man sed` is your friend. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the first sample, you should use:

```
echo xxx,aaa | sed 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\2,\1/'
```

For the second sample, simply use a character other than slash as the delimiter:

```
echo xxx/aaa | sed 's%\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)%\2/\1%'
```

You can also use `\{1,\}` to formally require one or more:

```
echo xxx,aaa | sed 's/\([^,]\{1,\}\),\([^,]\{1,\}\)/\2,\1/'
echo xxx/aaa | sed 's%\([^/]\{1,\}\)/\([^/]\{1,\}\)%\2/\1%'
```

This uses the most portable `sed` notation; it should work anywhere.  With modern versions that support extended regular expressions (`-r` with GNU `sed`, `-E` with Mac OS X or BSD `sed`), you can lose some of the backslashes and use `+` in place of `*` which is more precisely what you're after (and parallels `\{1,\}` much more succinctly):

```
echo xxx,aaa | sed -E 's/([^,]+),([^,]+)/\2,\1/'
echo xxx/aaa | sed -E 's%([^/]+)/([^/]+)%\2/\1%'
```

Comment: It is worth remembering that `x+` is syntatic sugar for `xx*`.